# Regular expression custom word boundary .Net

Tags: .net, regex

I am trying to match the following types of strings:

123456

1234.56

123,456

1,234.56

.123456

I want to make sure that these strings aren't matched:

12,34.56

1.23,456

This is what I've come up with so far (with help from a previous post on this forum):

```
(?<acreage>((\d{1,3}(,\d{3})+)?|\d*)\.\d+|(\d{1,3}(,\d{3})+|\d+)\.?)
```

This is matching all the valid strings, but it is also matching parts of the invalid strings.

What I'd like is to put some kind of boundary condition at the start, but it can't be a ^ character because there might be text before the acreage I'm trying to match.  The \b character treats commas as a word boundary and so for a string like the following,

12,34,567.89

It will return 34,567.89 when I really want it to fail to match any part of the string.

I will be checking for specific characters after the acreage string, so I'm not so worried about it doing goofy stuff like getting 123,456 & 7 from 123,4567.

Could someone please help me to get this to only match the valid strings and not match any of the invalid strings?

Comment: You could try matching all of them with `[\d,.]+` and then discarding those which don't match your regex.

Comment: What do you mean by discarding the ones that don't match?  Wouldn't I need a separate regex to determine that?

Comment: Yes. Sometimes using a less strict regex and then rejecting those matches you don't want is the simplest solution.

Comment: But wouldn't I have to write a regex to determine which to reject?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using [Decimal.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73) and specifying the `NumberStyles`? Do you specifically need a regular expression?

Comment: I'm not sure...  It's a substring in a field that I'm importing from an outside source.  I can't trust that the source values are valid, so I want to be strict.  Also, what if there are multiple matches in a given substring?

Comment: Taking from the example above, since your valid list is longer than your invalid list, why don't you match for invalids and then weed it out. `Regex re = new Regex(@"[.,]\d{2}[.,]");` will match invalids assuming a simple case of 2 digits between a ',' or '.' is invalid

Comment: I think I could get this sucker to work if I could just find a way of defining a word boundary that doesn't include commas.  Is that possible?

Comment: Thank you for all the responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this enough?

```
(?<![\d.,])(?<acreage>((\d{1,3}(,\d{3})+)?|\d*)\.\d+|(\d{1,3}(,\d{3})+|\d+)\.?)(?![\d.,])
```

I added a negative [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?<![\d.,])` and a negative [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?![\d.,])` assertion to your expression.

`(?<![\d.,])` ensures that there is no digit, no `.` and no `,` before

`(?![\d.,])` ensures that there is no digit, no `.` and no `,` following

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?31ps4)

That would be your personal number boundary, that checks that around your number are characters that are not allowed in the number.